# return vector without nth element (complement of (nth))

Tags: function, vector, clojure

I need to get a random value from a `vector` of `integers`.

I also need to get back the `vector` without the value key.

Example code is below. I know I can easily put this code in a `function` to reuse.

But wonder if there is some function or a better way to create a new `vector` without the nth element? (thus the complement of the (nth) `function` in core clojure)

```
(let [ vector [1 2 3 5 9 1]
       id (rand-int (count vector))
       value (nth vector id)
       head (take id vector)
       tail (drop (+ id 1) vector)
       vector (flatten [head tail])]
  {:value value :new-vector vector})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vector data structure cannot efficiently remove a single element. If you are doing this often, you should generally be using a more suitable data structure. For example, if the elements of your vector are distinct, you could use a set (or sorted-set, if order is important to you in other cases). Or if they're not distinct, but you never care about order, you can do a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://github.com/flatland/useful/blob/develop/src/flatland/useful/seq.clj#L149-L171) - here we use a vector, but avoid the "removing from the middle is expensive" problem by swapping one in the middle with the element on the end, and then removing from the end instead.

Comment: One more suitable data structure that is similar to vectors is the [rrb-vector](https://github.com/clojure/core.rrb-vector). Slicing and concatenation are done in logarithmic time.

Comment: I did not use the function you linked to but it inspired me to look into the clojure.core `shuffle` function in combination with `first`/`rest`. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 2):

Heed @amalloy's advice but if you still want to create a function you can do something like this

```
(defn sans-nth [v idx]
  "Takes in a vector and an index. 
   Returns value at index and removes value from vector"
  (let [x (get @v idx)
        y #(vec (concat (take idx %) (drop (inc idx) %)))]
        (swap! v y)
        x))
```

Example

```
(def v (atom [1 2 3 4 5 6]))
```

'user/v

```
(sans-nth v 3)
```

4

```
@v
```

[1 2 3 5 6]

If you need to just remove an element from a vector

```
(defn remove-nth [v i]
  (vec (concat (take i v) (drop (inc i) v))))
```